# I can't draw parallel lines in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I will draw lines in Panel, they should lie parallel. I create the following code, but when I run this code, then the lines lie one above the other. What I make wrong?

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
Line line1 = new Line(0, 50, 100, 50);
line1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
Line line2 = new Line(0, 40, 100, 40);
line2.setStroke(Color.RED);
stackPane.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2);
Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 300, 250);
stage.setTitle("Gerasterte Karte");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Comment: If the answer I posted below is helpful, please up vote it. If the answer I posted below fixes the problem you're experiencing, please mark it as the selected answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're experiencing has to do with how StackPane lays out it's children. By default it puts each of it's children in the center of the pane. So your lines are being drawn on top of each other, which is not what you want.

See the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14780577/328275) to this question for a solution to the problem you're having.

**Example:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Pane stackPane = new Pane();
    Line line1 = new Line(0, 50, 100, 50);
    line1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    Line line2 = createParallelLine(0, 40, line1);
    line2.setStroke(Color.RED);
    stackPane.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 300, 250);
    stage.setTitle("Gerasterte Karte");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  /**
   * Returns a new line that is parallel to, and the same length as,
   * the specified source line which starts at the point specified by
   * the coordinates (x, y).
   *
   * @param x the x coordinate of the starting point of the returned line.
   * @param y the y coordinate of the starting point of the returned line.
   * @param source the line that is used to calculate the slope and distance
   *               of the new line which is to be returned.
   * @return a new line that is parallel to, and the same length as,
   * the specified source line which starts at the point specified by
   * the coordinates (x, y).
   */
  private Line createParallelLine(double x, double y, Line source) {
    double d = getLength(source);
    double m = getSlope(source);
    double r = Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(m, 2));
    double endX = x + d / r;
    double endY = y + ((d * m) / r);
    return new Line(x, y, endX, endY);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the slope of the specified line.
   * @param line whose slope is to be returned.
   * @return the slope of the specified line.
   */
  private double getSlope(Line line) {
    return (line.getEndY() - line.getStartY()) / (line.getEndX() - line.getStartX());
  }

  /**
   * Returns the length of the specified line.
   * @param line whose length is to be returned.
   * @return the length of the specified line.
   */
  private double getLength(Line line) {
    return Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(line.getEndX() - line.getStartX(), 2) +
        Math.pow(line.getEndY() - line.getStartY(), 2)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please vote up my answer and mark it selected.